# How can I use python-click to make a multi-command CLI interface

Tags: python, python-click

I'd like to create a CLI for my application that's flexible and extensible. Click seems like the right solution but I'm new to it and have not seen an example that fits what I'm looking for. The application has a variety of different inputs (file, TCP socket, ZMQ etc); a variety of different tasks it can perform (task1, task2, etc); and a variety of outputs (file, socket, etc). I'd like to have a CLI which allows the defining of these 3 stages.

Desired CLI example:

```
myapp.py \
  source TCP --read-size=4096 127.0.0.1 8888 \
  task taskABC --optional-arg example example 99 \
  sink file myoutput.bin
```

The following code seems to provide most of what I want but only allows the specification of 1 of the 3 pipelines. Using the `chain=True` option on the top level group yields the error `RuntimeError: It is not possible to add multi commands as children to another multi command` and doesn't feel like the right answer as I want to require the specification of all 3 stages, not allow an arbitrary number of stage definitons.

Is my CLI vision achievable with Click?

````py
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group()
def source():
    pass

@source.command()
@click.argument("host")
@click.argument("port", type=click.INT)
def tcp(host, port):
    """Command for TCP based source"""

@source.command()
@click.argument("input_file", type=click.File('rb'))
def file(input_file):
    """Command for file based source"""

@cli.group()
def task():
    pass

@task.command()
def example1():
    """Example 1"""

@task.command()
def example2():
    """Example 2"""

@cli.group()
def sink():
    pass

@sink.command()
@click.argument("host", type=click.STRING)
@click.argument("port", type=click.INT)
def tcp(host, port):
    """Command for TCP based sink"""

@sink.command()
@click.argument("output_file", type=click.File('wb'))
def file(output_file):
    """Command for file based source"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()```
````

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `click` according to the [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#multi-command-chaining) where it says "It is currently not possible for chain commands to be nested. This will be fixed in future versions of Click."

Comment: Have you considered for the time being prompting the user for input for those commands, to set up those method invocations yourself, and simply calling them, for the time being? While I can appreciate your approach makes a lot of sense, Click was always created for this sort of interactive approach.